# Value of the string variable how to use inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to plot a graph which is using a array as:

```
$min = array('A'=>30, 'B'=>30, 'C'=>50);
```

Now fetching values from database i manage to create a string and stored it in a variable as:

```
$a = "'A'=>30, 'B'=>30, 'C'=>50";
```

and want to use it as:

```
$min = array($a);
```

but its not working..any right way to do this ??
Thanks

Comment: please write question in proper english language.

Comment: Why are you creating a string like that? Why not just fetch the values from the database and put them in an array?

Comment: you should store it as json format would be easy to handle as `{"A":"30","B":"30","C":"50"}`

Comment: Just a comment: Storing values like this in a DB isn't good design.

Answer (score 0):

```
$min = eval('array(' . $a . ');');
```

But beware of dangerous code in your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = "'A'=>30, 'B'=>30, 'C'=>50";
eval("\$min = array($a);");
var_dump($min);
```

output:

```
array(3) { ["A"]=> int(30) ["B"]=> int(30) ["C"]=> int(50) }
```

read:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php